# What message does "should you decide to accept" really convey?

Tags: phrase-meaning, conditional-constructions

In 'Mission Impossible' movies a recurring phrase is

> ... your mission, should you decide to accept it, is ...

Which of the below alternatives best catches the true meaning of the sentence?

- ... your mission, if you should decide to accept it, is ...
- ... your mission, if you decide to accept it, is ...
- ... your mission, if you were to decide to accept it, is ...
- ... your mission, if you were to accept it, is ...
- ... your mission, if you accept it, is ...

The question whether *should* can be replaced by *if* was already asked [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/should-if-you-choose.1017170/) and one answerer said that *if* is weaker because *should* implies an underlying duty or moral obligation. Another answerer thought *should* is more formal.

I think *if* is the most neutral (and least colorful) way of anouncing the mission whereas  *should* expresses at least some doubt on the part of the person that makes the proposition.

Who can shed a light on this?

These wikipedia articles [English_subjunctive#Inversion_in_condition_clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Inversion_in_condition_clauses) and [English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses) nicely explain why this "should you" approach exists and that my first alternative sentence is the correct one, but of course do not address my suspicion about *should* expressing doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Both *should* and *if* express a degree of doubt. They both acknowledge the possibility that the person being addressed will not accept it. *Should* just comes across as slightly more formal.

Answer (score -1):

I would say the alternative that best catches the true meaning of the sentence

> ... your mission, should you decide to accept it, is ...

Is (in my opinion):

> ... your mission, if you decide to accept it, is ...